# Nested Whgridview. Grids disappear on sort or pagination click

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I'm a newbie in Yii programming.

I'm using boostrap library on Yii via Yiistrap/Yiiwheels

I've created a relation table view

The related view is a Whgridview itself

The first (master grid) has a TbRelationColum clicking it i display the second grid (detail grid).
When I click on the row to display the sub grid, everything appears ok. When I change the sort order or the page of the sub grid disappear both grid.

I understand we should differentiate the css class of the pager and the sort of sub grid from the main grid. How to do this specifically in Yii-Way?

Is This the problem?

This is the view of the main grid:

```
$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.grid.WhGridView',array(
        'id'=>'masterGrid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'template' => "{summary}{items}<div class=\"row-fluid\"><div class=\"pull-right\">{pager}</div></div>",
        'type' => array(TbHtml::GRID_TYPE_BORDERED, TbHtml::GRID_TYPE_STRIPED),   
        'columns'=>array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'yiiwheels.widgets.grid.WhRelationalColumn',
                    //'name' => 'multiMembers.id',
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'header' => 'Sub Items',
                    'url' => $this->createUrl('multiGroup/ajaxSubItems'),
                    'cacheData' => false,
                    'value' => "CHtml::tag('button',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'),'Sub Items')",
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:90px;'),
                    'cssClass' => 'showSubItems',
                ),            
                'id',
                'title',
                array(
                        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                ),
        ),
));
```

This is the sub-grid:

```
echo CHtml::tag('h3',array(),'Sub Items Group #"'.$id.'"');
$this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.grid.WhGridView', array(
    'id'=>'subGrid_'.$id,
    'type'=>array(TbHtml::GRID_TYPE_BORDERED, TbHtml::GRID_TYPE_STRIPED),
    'dataProvider' => $gridDataProvider,
    'template' => "{summary}{items}<div class=\"row-fluid\"><div class=\"pull-right\">{pager}</div></div>",
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ));
```

This is the controller:

```
    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
            $model=new MultiGroup('search');
            $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
            if (isset($_GET['MultiGroup'])) {
                    $model->attributes=$_GET['MultiGroup'];
            }

            $this->render('admin',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
            ));
    }

    public function actionAjaxSubItems()
    {
        $id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        if($model->numSubItems > 0) {
            $this->renderPartial('_child', array('id' => $id, 
                                                 'gridDataProvider' => $this->getGridDataProvider($id),
                                                 'gridColumns' => $this->getGridColumns()
                                            ), false, true);
        } else {
            echo 'Non ci sono Sub Items.';
        }
    }

    public function getGridDataProvider($id) {

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM multi_member WHERE groupid = :groupid ORDER BY lastname,firstname';
        $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $cmd->bindParam(':groupid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result = $cmd->queryAll();

        $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider(
                    $result, array(
                        'sort' => array(
                            'attributes' => array('id','groupid','firstname','lastname','membersince'),
                            'defaultOrder' => array('lastname' => CSort::SORT_ASC, 'firstname' => CSort::SORT_ASC),
                            ),
                        'pagination' => array(
                            'pageSize' => 2,
                        ),
                      ));

        return $dataProvider;

    }

    public function getGridColumns() {

        return array('id', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'membersince');

    }
```

How can I do?
thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

If the extensions you're using all extend `CGgridView`, then you should be able to use option `'ajaxUpdate'` ([link to documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#ajaxUpdate-detail)).

Try setting `'ajaxUpdate'=>false` in one of the grids (or in both of them) to see whether it helps you.

Sometimes setting `ajaxUpdate` to false is the only way I get get some grids to behave the way I want them to...